# Wrong encoding from a jsp input form

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java Struts 1 application running on Tomcat 9 servlet and from an input jsp form all the germans chars (umlaut etc) are not correctly encoded. The tricky fact is that happens only in one server and not in my local or other. What should I check? Is it something related to the Tomcat configuration?

UPDATE
I noticed that on the html page (in the server where the issue happens) is missing the content-type while in server where it works the content type is correctly defined. Is this content-type missing in the header the cause of the issue?

Comment: What OS is there on your local machine and Server?

Comment: my localmachine is windows, on the servers I am not sure but they should all have the same OS but only in one of them does not work

Comment: This might be worth trying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868133/http-response-decoding-behaves-differently-from-windows-to-linux

Comment: @Flav I have updated the post

Comment: You may have different / missing `LANG` environment variable on the servers, or Java `file.encoding` system property set differently.

Comment: @OriDar is the missing content type in the header that create the issue?

Comment: @OriDar are this environment variable set up also on local environment?

Comment: Yes. Depending on your OS, see instructions of how to set `LANG` and other locale variables. For docker, use the `ENV LANG [german encoding]`.  `file.encoding` is not an env. variable, but a JVM system property used to override the machine encoding inside the JVM. use:  `-Dfile.encoding=[encoding]` in order to override